# Web Application can't find my API after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

This is my first project using ASP.Net Core and I've come across some problems which I was mostly able to solve myself. However, right now I am running into a problem that my web application can't find my API after the publish on our server.

First, it's important to know that there are 2 applications inside my project
[image]

Inside the API I have a few controllers with the default routing
    ie: `[Route("api/Address")]` when I launch the Web Application through Visual Studio everything runs fine and without problems.
Now I am trying to publish the application.

**So I published(Localy)** the application and copy pasted it into the inetpub/wwwroot/somefolder. Checked the folder structure and I can clearly see that there is a BetonApi.dll inside. Which is great. as I do want to publish the API as a stand-alone web api just yet. I want to use it in the form as a **.dll** and this works perfectly. I can see the grid in my application and the data is properly retrieved from the BetonAPI.

[image]

**When Published on the server**, however I get the error that the API was not found. I've tried to play around with the URL as that was the first thing which crossed my mind, I checked if the BetonAPI.dll was inside the publish folder. Tried some google research but I couldn't find something similar.

[image]

**Long story short:**

- Application does fetch data from API when started through VS
- Application does fetch data from API after publishing locally
- Application does **not** fetch data from API after publishing on server.

Comment: Did you initiate under services

Comment: @UdaraKasun Uhm no but I didn't do that on my local machine neither.

Comment: "When Published on the server"? Note that if you hardcoded `http://localhost` in your web app, in any browser (on any machine) it would try to locate the web API at localhost, which is only valid when the browser is on the server itself.

Comment: @LexLi No I didn't hardcode Localhost in my app nor api. I am getting the base url from my startup.cs also I am running this on the server's browser.

Comment: You might use FRT to see what gives you 404, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Without more data at hand, the cause should be clear.

Comment: Is your application and api are different project or same project?

Comment: its a different application inside the same .sln

Comment: Did you check http or https